# Read Dataframe from IoT Evenhubs using Spark streaming in Databricks

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks, azure-iot-hub

I am loading data from an event hub as a dataframe using a spark streaming request on databricks.

I realized that there is latency, the job is processing data late. Looking closer I realized that the dataframe received are more and more huge (**6000 to 7000 frames** per dataframe).

Do you have any idea how to avoid this latency? Knowing that in terms of memory and CPU both are not exploited at 100% so the problem does not come from there.

I also modified the parameter `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to 1000 knowing that by default it is 200 but still the same problem

Updated with code from the comments:

This is the query that i call:

```py
read_df = ( spark.readStream .format("eventhubs") .options(**conf) .load() ) 

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

streamingDF=read_df.select(col("partition"), col("offset"),col("sequenceNumber"),
  col("enqueuedTime"), col("publisher"),col("partitionKey"),
  col("body").cast("string")) 

query = (streamingDF.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='4 minutes') \
  .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function3).start())
```

Comment: please provide a sample of code how you're reading & writing data, etc. For example, is it continuos streaming vs Trigger.Once, do you use checkpoints, etc.

Comment: This is the query that i call :
query = (streamingDF.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='4 minutes').foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function3).start())

Comment: read_df = (
  spark.readStream
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(**conf)
    .load()
)
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

Comment: streamingDF=read_df.select(col("partition"), col("offset"),col("sequenceNumber"),col("enqueuedTime"), col("publisher"),col("partitionKey"), col("body").cast("string"))

Comment: Please consider updating your question with these details, as it's becoming difficult to read.